# Word for non-consecutive numbers?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for a pair of numbers like 6 and 8, which are two apart? Another example would be 11 and 13.
Thanks!

Comment: This is a good question. You might like to ask it on ELU as well.

Comment: @Dog I've seen times when asking the same question on both sites is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context you can call these numbers "consecutive odd numbers" or "consecutive even numbers".

6 and 8 are consecutive even numbers. 11 and 13 are consecutive odd numbers.

You are most likely to encounter this usage in a math problem, like "name two consecutive odd numbers whose sum equals 24".